# Removing a file from a certain commit (back in history) in git

Tags: git, gerrit

Imagine that you have committed several changes (in separate commits). For example, we have 3 commits: A , B and C.

Now, you have found out that in the commit B you have added a certain file (including some changes) that you shouldn't have committed.

How would you remove that file in that commit?

An example would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD
```

This command will remove a file from all commits [from history].

**Warning:** If you've already shared your work with others, it's not recommended to use this command. Please make sure you understood the full implications before using this command.

Comment: But removing a file from all commits is not really desirable. Maybe this file has been push once long time ago and didn't have to be changed and pushed again, right?

Comment: @Hossein depends on whether you want to purge it from the history or not. If not, then just deleting the file on next commit will probably be better. If you want to remove it from the whole history, because e.g. you had some private data inside (like passwords), you're probably out of luck anyway if someone already fetched your commits - see this [Mercurial FAQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.I_committed_a_change_containing_nuclear_launch_codes.2C_how_do_I_delete_it_permanently.3F) which applies to all DVCSs.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do

```
git rebase --interactive A
```

and edit commit B not to include the file in question

but same warning applies
and if you made changes to file in any commit after B these will fail to apply